# How to keep bash function parameters from being expanded

Tags: bash, unix

I have a bash function like the following:

```
foo() {
    echo $1
}
```

or

```
bar() {
    baz $1
}
```

If I then call `foo 'file[1-3]'` the result is `file1 file2 file3`, not `file[1-3]`. Analogous phenomenon happens when passing the parameter to a call of another bash function like in the function `bar`. What's the easiest way around this besides ensuring that there are no matching files in the current directory so that I can reference the parameter when echoing or passing the parameter to another function?

EDIT: String matching doesn't seem to expand the glob. My specific problem manifested when performing a string match in the internal call to another function. It was the call to the other function that appears to have expanded the pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert this into the top of your script:

```
set -o noglob
```

Comment: And if you need globbing later in your script just re-enable it with `set +o noglob`

Comment: I ended up using `foo() { (set -o noglob; echo $1) }` to drop the setting at the end of the function, including when it's killed while running.

Comment: Using double-quotes (as in @doubleDown's answer) is a *far* better way to do this -- it doesn't cause problems with noglob being set in unexpected places, doesn't require spawning a subshell (as the `( )` approach does), and also avoids a number of other possible problems with `$1` undergoing unwanted parsing (e.g. word splitting).

Answer (score 1):

Just enclose $1 in double quotes, namely

```
echo "$1"
```

because globbing / filename expansion does not happen within double quotes.